# How to process a string into layer of sublists?

Tags: python, list, recursion, sublist

This is the example form, I'll try to explain it in words later.
I have a list from breaking up a string...

say

```
[a, a, a, b, a, a, b, a, c, a, b, a, a, c, a, c, a]
```

where b is criteria 1 and c is criteria 2

I want to break it into a list like this:

```
[a, a, a, [b, a, a, [b, a, c], a, [b, a, a, c], a, c], a]
```

So I want to process the string such that when I go through it, if the item matches criteria 1, open a new list, if item matches criteria 2, close the list and return one level above.

I've tried to do something like this, but it's not working very well.

```
def sublist(self, l):
  for line in list:
    if not b:
    self.data.append(line)
  else:
    sublist(l[line:])       #<-----  not sure how to recurse it.
```

I've seen breaking list into equal sized list before on stackoverflow, but not one breaking into sublist using a set of criteria.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here you go:

```
lst = "aaabaabacabaacaca"

def go(it):
    for x in it:
        if x == 'b':
            yield [x] + list(go(it))
        else:
            yield x
            if x == 'c':
                break 


print list(go(iter(lst)))
```

Comment: Nice. Generators definitely simplify the recursive structure.

Comment: Note that this handles an "underflow" by terminating the output. This might not be what is wanted.

Comment: Does exactly what I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
addlist = []
alllists = []
for item in mylist:
    if item == b:
       newlist = [item]
       addlist.append(newlist)
       alllists.append(addlist)
       addlist = newlist
    elif item == c:
       addlist.append(item)
       addlist = alllists.pop()
    else:
       addlist.append(item)
```

The above will work as long as your `b` and `c` delimiters are balanced; in particular, if you have an excess of `c`s, you will have a stack underflow.

While I frequently like recursive solutions, this has the advantage of making the stack explicit, which in this case, in my opinion, leads to easier to grok code.

Answer (score 1):

with a stack:

```
def parseList(inList):
    stack = [[]]
    for element in inList:
        if element == 'b':
            stack.append([element])
            stack[-2].append(stack[-1])
        elif element == 'c':
            stack.pop().append(element)
        else:
            stack[-1].append(element)
    return stack[0]
```

this will break if there are more 'c's than 'b's

Comment: This solution doesn't work, with the example in OP's question it produces an `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

There are very nice answers for this question, I particularly liked thg435's recursive solution using generators and Marcin's iterative solution which adds elements to referenced lists.

I also found unsettling that some solutions modify the input list, or use global state. That, IMHO, goes against the true spirit of a recursive solution. Below is my attempt at a purely functional, recursive solution in Python - granted, there are much more idiomatic and efficient ways to solve this problem, but I wanted to write an answer as I'd have written it in a purely functional programming language:

```
# lst: the list to be processed
# acc: accumulated result
# stk: temporary stack
def process(lst, acc, stk):
    if not lst:
        return acc
    elif lst[0] == 'b':
        return process(lst[1:], [lst[0]], [acc] + stk)
    elif lst[0] == 'c':
        return process(lst[1:], stk[0] + [acc + [lst[0]]], stk[1:])
    else:
        return process(lst[1:], acc + [lst[0]], stk)

lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a']
process(lst, [], [])
> ['a', 'a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a', 'c'], 'a', 'c'], 'a']
```

Some details to notice:

- I don't use local variables or global variables, only function parameters for keeping track of state
- I don't use assignment operators
- No iterators or loops are used for traversing the input list, only recursion
- It's a tail-recursive solution, although that's irrelevant in Python
- Only expressions are used; operations like `append` or `extend` (which return `None`) are avoided
- No lists are ever modified (including the input list), instead new lists are created as needed (using array slices for that)
- It's a rather short and elegant solution, but that might be a subjective opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

def sublist(l):
  ret = []
  while l:
    val = l.pop(0)
    if val == b:
      ret.append([val] + sublist(l))
    else:
      ret.append(val)
      if val == c: break
  return ret

l = [a, a, a, b, a, a, b, a, c, a, b, a, a, c, a, c, a]
print l
print sublist(l)
```

Note that this has the side-effect of modifying `l`.  It is trivial to change that by making a copy.

Answer (score 0):

In real recursion style you could do the following:

```
x = yourlist
i = 0
def lets_parse():
    global i
    fnlist = []
    while i < len(x)
        if x[i] == 'c':
            fnlist.append(x[i])
            i += 1
        return fnlist
        elif x[i] == 'b':
            i += 1
            f = lets_parse()
            f.insert(0, 'b')
            fnlist.append(f)
        else:
            fnlist.append(x[i])
            i += 1
return fnlist

print lets_parse()
```

Note the use of globals. A number of critics might object to it as bad coding style.

Comment: Indeed, it's bad coding style. In "real recursion" you don't need to use global variables, the result is passed around as parameters and return values of the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast    
mylist = '[a, a, a, b, a, a, b, a, c, a, b, a, a, c, a, c, a]'
mylist = mylist.replace('a','"a"')
mylist = mylist.replace('b','["b"')
mylist = mylist.replace('c','"c"]')
print ast.literal_eval(mylist)
#Output:
['a', 'a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a', ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'a', ['b', 'a', 'a', 'c'], 'a', 'c'], 'a']
```